# Swift Property Encapsulation

Tags: swift

I'm just wondering what the "standard" way of declaring a property in Swift is. In particular, it seems like all of Apple's Swift example code doesn't encapsulate the properties (you can freely get and set the property without having to go through getter and setter methods). (I'm used to Java so I have trouble believing that's how Apple expects developers to write code.)

Right now, I have:

```
private var x: Int
private var xListener: XListener?
public func getX() -> Int {
    return x
}
public func setX(newValue: Int) {
    x = newValue
    if (let listener = xListener) {
        listener.onXSet(x)
    }
}
```

But I feel like there must be a simpler way to do this. I saw some mention of computed properties but it seems like those don't store a value, so to use them you'd have to do:

```
private storedX: Int
public var x: Int {
    get {
        return storedX
    }
    set {
        storedX = newValue
    }
    didSet {
        if (let listener = xListener) {
            listener.onXSet(storedX)
        }
    }
}
```

I just have trouble believing that either of these methods are the "right" way to do this since they're so complicated. Does Swift not typically encapsulate properties, or am I just missing something?

Comment: Quite simply Swift is what the designer wanted and he did not want ivar encapsulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A setter and getter that do nothing provide no encapsulation at all vs just using the property. There's literally no semantic difference between this:

```
private storedX: Int
public var x: Int {
    get {
        return storedX
    }
    set {
        storedX = newValue
    }
}
```

and this

```
public var x: Int
```

You can always go back and change (albeit with the limitation that you have to recompile all linked code unless you have library evolution enabled) x to be a computed property later, or add didSet/willSet, etc...

Can you explain in more detail what you're seeking to gain by encapsulating x with a setter and getter that do the same thing as setting and getting it directly?

(edit: to directly answer the question though, I would do this:

```
public var x : Int {
    didSet {
        xListener?.onXSet(storedX)
    }
}
```

)

Comment: Sure. I'm keeping track of a user score in a game. Aside from obvious benefits of encapsulation (preventing the score from becoming negative, being able to change my stored representation of it later without changing how the rest of my code accesses it, better code "style" (from a java perspective), etc.), I also want to change other parts of the game such as difficulty level when the streak hits certain specific numbers. Because of this, I need to make sure the streak can only be incremented (increased by one) and not directly set.

Comment: Ok, that edit you made simplifies the code a little. I'm just surprised that I really need to keep a separate stored/private variable in addition to having the public "computed" variable. I guess I'm just wondering why "public var x" in your example can't/doesn't store an actual value.

Comment: But… public var x in my example *does* store an actual value. Adding a didSet doesn't make it a computed property. Similarly, you *can* change the representation later without changing how your code accesses it, you just change it to be a computed property. The only thing you've described that a separate setter might be needed for is restricting it to increment-only.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a little more, I found a slightly more elegant solution. It looks like there is a private(set) modifier that makes access to a variable public but prevents writing to it. So still not complete encapsulation but definitely better than allowing complete access to the field. So unless somebody has a better suggestion, my code will end up looking like this:

```
private(set) var x: Int
public func incrementX() {
    x++
    xListener?.onXIncremented()
}
```

Comment: You can clean this up a bit by marking x as "public private(set)" (and removing getX) and moving the listener code to didSet.

Answer (score -1):

Just to refine catfish's answer (which should be marked as answered by you):

In Java (and C++) you don't have properties so the "rule by convention" is to use always getter and setter methods. In Swift you can make myClass.x later on to a computed property (which is basically a get set method) if you do not want to change how your code is used.

In your own app this does not really matter even in Java because mose IDE's have really good refactoring tools but if you make a library for usage by others it does not break the interface. (at least on source code level)